# Rails model validation on form with new parent and child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, model, nested-form-for

I'm new to rails- but now wondering, are Rails validations lost on model objects when in my form I'm trying to create both the child and parent at the same time?

In my example (models in bold)
1 - **Cake** - has_many - **CakeDetails**

many - **CakeDetails** - belong_to 1 - **Size**

1 - **CakeType** - belongs_to 1 - **Cake**

I've managed to create a form That allows me to create a Cake, specify the sizes, associated prices and what type the cake will be.

But it seems all built in model validation is gone.

Is this correct? How do I bring validation back to my model objects?

When I render the new action I bring up a blank form and when I submit a blank form I get the following:

```
Started POST "/cakes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-25 21:19:03 +0100
Processing by CakesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"r6B2ult7w7z4vez95f2pNXmk7Q1rYSzj8Wi9VwnS4EgIAw8PG/w7isfAeiiSB9sY8+0+oHldMVpy1GFKBmrpmw==", "cake"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "cake_type_id"=>"", "cake_details_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"true", "price"=>""}, "1"=>{"_destroy"=>"true", "price"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Create Cake"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering cakes/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  CakeType Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "cake_types".* FROM "cake_types"
  Rendered cakes/_form.html.erb (15.9ms)
  Rendered cakes/new.html.erb within layouts/application (19.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 109ms (Views: 100.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

I get that its rolling back the transaction because there is no cake_type_id. But there is no errors displayed.

The following is the error displaying section in my form. 
I've tried adding more to check for errors in the nested object but not seeing anything.

```
  <% if @cake.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(cake.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cake from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @cake.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% @cake.cake_details.each do |detail| %>
    <% if detail.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(cake.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cake from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @cake.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

My Cake model

```
class Cake < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :description, :cake_type, presence: true

  belongs_to :cake_type
  has_many :cake_details, -> {order('size_id ASC')}, inverse_of: :cake
  has_many :sizes, through: :cake_details
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cake_details, :allow_destroy => true

  validates_associated  :cake_type, :cake_details
end
```

Cakes Controller

```
  def create
    #@cake = Cake.new(params[cake:{}])
    #params.require(:cake).permit(:name, :description,:cake_type_id)

    @cake = Cake.new(cake_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cake.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cake, notice: 'Cake was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cake }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cake.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def cake_only_params
  params.require(:cake).permit(:name, :description,:cake_type_id)
end

def cake_params
  params.require(:cake).permit(:name, :description,:cake_type_id, cake_type_id:[:type_id],
  cake_details_attributes:[:_destroy, :id, :cake_id, :size_id, :price])
end
```

**UPDATE**

I thought I had to access the variable I declared in my action e.g @cake
but I updated my form to use this

```
<%= form_with(model: cake, local: true) do |form| %>
```

instead of how I thought I needed it:

```
<%= form_with(model: @cake) do |form| %>
```

I'll read up on the docs but any comments on why I messed this up is definitely appreciated. Just starting to learn this framework... :/

Comment: What does "...it seems all built in model validation is gone" mean? How and where is your 'problem' manifesting itself?

Comment: added more detail- hope above has enough info. I can see the transaction doesn't commit but I don't see the errors display on the page when an empty form is submitted

Comment: Welp, I guess you might as well show us what your `CakesController.create` looks like. BTW, does that `error_explanation` div show up on your page? (PS, it looks like you would end up with multiple `divs` with `id='error_explanation'`. That's not good.)

Comment: more details added! yea - just wanted to see something anything validating! I'm not seeing any divs :( added params I was playing with also. Is it possible to just create the cake, then create the child records to force validation?

Comment: Got it... I had to changed the top of my form- I'll update the answer with how I had it and how it is now :/ thanks for replying so quickly though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I had to access the variable I declared in my action e.g

@cake

but I updated my form to use this:

```
<%= form_with(model: cake, local: true) do |form| %>
```

instead of how I thought I needed it:

```
<%= form_with(model: @cake) do |form| %>
```

and that works now.

Special thanks to jvillian for responding so quickly.

And noting that:

By adding `local: true` to `form_with`, you force the form to submit as `html` and your controller then uses `format.html`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a), and I'm sure elsewhere, in Rails 5, all forms created with `form_with` are remote by default (i.e., submit as `js`).

By adding `local: true` to `form_with`, you force the form to submit as `html` and your controller then uses `format.html`.